# Object getting null value FromForm in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

API controller and the request send from react app.

When using `FromForm` only then getting null value

```
    [Route("PotService")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] ServiceInfo serviceInfo)
    {
        //using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        //{
        //    service.Images.CopyToAsync(stream);
        //}
        bool result = _serManager.AddService(serviceInfo);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: You have `Consumes("application/json")` and then using `[FromForm]`. If you're expecting Json then use `[FromBody]`. `[FromForm]` is for `"application/x-www-url-formencoded"`

Comment: totally agree with Yitz

Comment: NO it's not happening, when i use "application/x-www-url-formencoded" and [FromForm] not hit my controller, i also change on my frontend






const res = await fetch(newSerPost, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-url-formencoded; carset=UTF-8',
      },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Consumes attribute specifies data types that an action accepts. If you are using `application/json`, it will receive the parameters transferred via the request body. And from your frontend code, it also seems that you are transfer the data from body, so, try to use the `[FromBody]` attribute and use the following code.

```
[Route("PotService")]
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ServiceInfo serviceInfo)
{
    //using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    //{
    //    service.Images.CopyToAsync(stream);
    //}
    bool result = _serManager.AddService(serviceInfo);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

[image]

If you want to send the parameters via the Form, try to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` data type.

Refer to the following screenshot:

[image]