# x-www-form-urlencoded content type is not working on server

Tags: .net, identityserver4, iis-10, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a .net6 API hosted on windows server on IIS 10.

I have the following controller that has an endpoint with POST method and the body content type is x-www-form-urlencoded

The problem is the body is always comes null on the server.

What could be the cause of this issue?

```
namespace testapp.Controllers
{
    public class TestInput
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/<TestController>
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public TestInput Post([FromForm] TestInput value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

here is how I make the API call

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:7158/api/Test' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'name=john doe' \
--data-urlencode 'age=22'
```

- I have tried to disable the firewall on the server
- I have disabled all the request filtering on IIS

but still have the issue

Comment: You can refer to this answer about x-www-form-urlencoded: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73770077/20058276.

Comment: That answer provides no help.